# I can't install Lync 2010 at windows server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, lync, lync-2010

I'm still trying to install Microsoft Lync at VM Windows Server 2008. But its always failed at "Prepare first Standard Edition Server". The error message is this. 
"Checking prerequisite SqlExpressRtc.. installing...failure code -2068578304".

Is anybody know how to solve it? I try to search on google, but still failed. I also try to uninstall my sql server, still failed.. :D

thanks.

Comment: You might be better off sticking this on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because you are trying to install SQLServer 2008 Express Edition prerrequisite on a Domain Controller, and the Lync Server setup always try to install SQL Server Express with NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService account to Start the service, and this isn't allowed in a Domain Controller.

You need to execute manually the stament to install SQL Server 2008 Express edition, but changing the NetworkService account for SYSTEM account (or a domain account) ... would be something like this:

**"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Lync Server\Deployment\cache\4.0.7577.0\SQLEXPR_x64.exe" /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQLEngine,Tools /INSTANCENAME=RTC /TCPENABLED=1 /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Builtin\Administrators" /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic**

Comment: thanks for your answer. I fix the issue. but i will mark this as an answer. thanks.